# Do $f(x^*+a,y^*) \le f(x^*,y^*)$ and $f(x^*,y^*+b) \le f(x^*,y^*)$ imply $f(x^*,y^*) \le f(x,y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f(x,y)$ are twice continuously differentiable. Suppose $U$ is a neighborhood of $(x^*,y^*),$ where $(x^*,y^*)$ is a critical point, i.e. the gradient at this point is zero.

If for all $(x^*+a,y^*)$ and $(x^*,y^*+b)$ in $U,$ we have $f(x^*+a,y^*) \ge f(x^*,y^*)$ and $f(x^*,y^*+b) \ge f(x^*,y^*).$

Can we conclude that $f(x^*,y^*) \le f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in U$?

Intuitively, I guess this is correct. But I don't know how to prove it rigorously.

If not, what else conditions do we need?

Thanks.

---

For $f(x^*+a,y^*) \ge f(x^*,y^*)$ and $f(x^*,y^*+b) \ge f(x^*,y^*)$, someone has given a counterexample.

If the conditions have been changed to $f(x^*+a,y^*) > f(x^*,y^*)$ and $f(x^*,y^*+b) > f(x^*,y^*),$ Is the statement $f(x^*,y^*) \le f(x,y)$ true?

Comment: Consider function $f(x,y) = (x-x^*)(y-y^*)$, your conditions are satisfied.  But $f(x^*, y^*) = 0$, $f(x^*+1, y^*+1) = 1$, and $f(x^*+1, y^*-1) = -1$.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If $f(x^*,y^*)<f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in U$ then how can $f(x^*+a,y^*)<f(x^*,y^*)$ for $(x^*+a,y)\in U$??

Comment: I guess in your statement you mean the reverse inequality $f(x^*+a,y^*) >f(x^*,y^*)$ and $f(x^*,y^*+b) > f(x^*,y^*)$ as otherwise it makes no sense...

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. Thank you so much!

Comment: Pls, add new edit. I think the inequalities are shown incorrectly. By employing the gradient concept, you can show the function is strictly ascending or descending.

Comment: You have the assumption that the partial functions $x \mapsto f(x, y^*)$ and $y \mapsto f(x^*, y)$ have a minimum at $x^*$ and at $y^*,$ resp. Of course, this can't imply a minimum when both $x$ and $y$ are allowed to vary freely. Simply construct a function that behaves badly through a diagonal. The fact that $f$ is $\mathsf{C}^k$ for large $k$ is not very important here (maybe if the function were analytic...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no in general. Consider for instance
$$f(x, y) = -x^2y^2\,.$$
Then $f$ attains it maximum in $(0,0)$, although your condition holds.

Note that you can easily modify this example to find counterexamples to your statement where the inequalities are strict for $a,b\neq 0$.

For instance, you can check that $(0,0)$ is not a local minimum for
$$f(x, y) = \frac{1}{4}(x^4 +y^4)-x^2y^2\,.$$
To see it you can notice that $f(t, t)<0$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!